# Improving my query which is build by many subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got 4 tables used in the following query.
`campaigns_programs`, `conversions`, `campaigns`, `applications`

Table Structure of them:

```
CREATE TABLE `campaigns` 
(  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
   `app_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
   `media_source` varchar(64) NOT NULL,  
   `campaign_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,  
   `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  
   `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
   UNIQUE KEY `media_source` (`media_source`,`campaign_name`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `campaigns_programs` 
(  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
   `campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
   `program_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
   `value` float NOT NULL,  
   `pixel_url` varchar(512) NOT NULL,  
   `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
   `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
   UNIQUE KEY `campaign_id` (`campaign_id`,`program_id`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `conversions` 
(  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
   `campaign_program_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
   `value` double NOT NULL,  
   `pixel_url` varchar(512) NOT NULL,  
   `pixel_response` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,  
   `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `applications` 
(  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
   `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,  
   `appflyers_id` varchar(256) NOT NULL,  
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


SELECT
    `c`.`media_source` AS `media_source`,
    `c`.`campaign_name` AS `campaign_name`,
    `app`.`name` AS `application`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `conversions` AS `c` LEFT JOIN `campaigns_programs` `cp` ON (`c`.`campaign_program_id` = `cp`.`id`) WHERE `cp`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`id` AND `cp`.`program_id` = 1) AS `installs_amount`,
    (SELECT SUM(`c`.`value`) FROM `conversions` AS `c` LEFT JOIN `campaigns_programs` `cp` ON (`c`.`campaign_program_id` = `cp`.`id`) WHERE `cp`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`id` AND `cp`.`program_id` = 1) AS `installs_value`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `conversions` AS `c` LEFT JOIN `campaigns_programs` `cp` ON (`c`.`campaign_program_id` = `cp`.`id`) WHERE `cp`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`id` AND `cp`.`program_id` = 2) AS `first_purchases_amount`,
    (SELECT SUM(`c`.`value`) FROM `conversions` AS `c` LEFT JOIN `campaigns_programs` `cp` ON (`c`.`campaign_program_id` = `cp`.`id`) WHERE `cp`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`id` AND `cp`.`program_id` = 2) AS `first_purchases_value`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `conversions` AS `c` LEFT JOIN `campaigns_programs` `cp` ON (`c`.`campaign_program_id` = `cp`.`id`) WHERE `cp`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`id` AND `cp`.`program_id` = 3) AS `purchases_amount`,
    (SELECT SUM(`c`.`value`) FROM `conversions` AS `c` LEFT JOIN `campaigns_programs` `cp` ON (`c`.`campaign_program_id` = `cp`.`id`) WHERE `cp`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`id` AND `cp`.`program_id` = 3) AS `purchases_value`
FROM 
    `campaigns` AS `c`
LEFT JOIN
    `applications` `app` ON (`app`.`id` = `c`.`app_id`)
WHERE 
    `c`.`user_id` = 1;
```

Im sure my query will be really slow it has alot of subqueries. 
How can I improve my query?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? can you provide some sample data and the required result?

Comment: Do you realize that the four subqueries are returning the same value on all rows?

Comment: @mureinik Im trying to get total value and conversions amount of specific program (1,2,3) of specific user

Answer (score 1):

All the sub queries are doing much the same thing. If we convert them to a single query as follows we can save the rest. The query optimiser may figure out the same pattern but this is very explicit.

```
SELECT `cp`.`campaign_id`, `cp`.`program_id`, COUNT(*) as 'ProgramCount', SUM(`c`.`value`) as 'ProgramSum'
FROM `conversions` AS `c` 
LEFT JOIN `campaigns_programs` `cp` ON `c`.`campaign_program_id` = `cp`.`id` 
WHERE `cp`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`id`
GROUP By `cp`.`campaign_id`, `cp`.`program_id`
```

Not entirely sure what you want to achieve but this gives you the count and sumtotal for each campaign program...

Answer (score 0):

First, using the same alias on an inner subquery as the alias in the outer can lead to confusion.   I would change that.  Second, since each of your column-based aggregates are the same basis, just different condition and would move them to a single pre-query with SUM( case/when ) applied.

```
SELECT
      c.media_source,
      c.campaign_name,
      app.`name` AS application,
      COALESCE( PreQuery.ID1Counts, 0 ) as installs_counts,
      COALESCE( PreQuery.ID1Values, 0 ) as installs_values,
      COALESCE( PreQuery.ID2Counts, 0 ) as first_purchases_counts,
      COALESCE( PreQuery.ID2Values, 0 ) as first_purchases_values,
      COALESCE( PreQuery.ID3Counts, 0 ) as purchases_counts,
      COALESCE( PreQuery.ID3Values, 0 ) as purchases_values
FROM campaigns AS c
LEFT JOIN applications app 
        ON app.id = c.app_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                 cp.campaign_id,
                 SUM( CASE when cp.program_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) ID1Counts,
                 SUM( CASE when cp.program_id = 1 then cnv.value else 0 end ) ID1Values,
                 SUM( CASE when cp.program_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end ) ID2Counts,
                 SUM( CASE when cp.program_id = 2 then cnv.value else 0 end ) ID2Values,
                 SUM( CASE when cp.program_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end ) ID3Counts,
                 SUM( CASE when cp.program_id = 3 then cnv.value else 0 end ) ID3Values
           FROM campaigns AS c1
           JOIN conversions cnv
              ON c1.id = cnv.campaign_program_id
           LEFT JOIN campaigns_programs cp
                   ON cnv.campaign_program_id = cp.id
                    AND cp.program_id in ( 1, 2, 3 )
           WHERE
                 c1.user_id = 1
           GROUP BY                     
                    cp.campaign_id ) PreQuery
            ON c.id = PreQuery.campaign_id 

   WHERE 
        c.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN ( SELECT cp.campaign_id, S' at line 12

Comment: @DinRevah - There was two `FROM` clauses, and the `PreQuery` reference needed to be later in the statement.